# Cython: Symbol not found: _PyCFunction_Check

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to get the [basic Cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html) to work. So I have

`hello.pyx`:

```
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

And `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

However, trying to compile I get this error:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
failed to import Cython: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCFunction_Check
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so
error: Cython does not appear to be installed
```

Cython *is* installed and `scanning.so` does appear to contain the symbol in question:

```
$ nm -gl /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so | grep _PyCFunction_Check
             U _PyCFunction_Check
```

Any ideas? I'm on OS X 10.7.5 using homebrew python 2.7.3.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @bdash' comment below, `U _PyCFunction_Check` actually means that  `_PyCFunction_Check` is undefined.

Comment: U _PyCFunction_Check indicates that the symbol is undefined (e.g., referenced by the binary in question and expected to be provided by some other library).

Comment: Ahh, that explains a lot. So something is missing. Do you know how to find out where this other library should be located, @bdash?

Comment: No. I'm not sure why it'd even be looking for a symbol named PyCFunction_Check. As far as I can see from the Python source that is the name of a preprocessor macro (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Include/methodobject.h) and thus should not exist at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking into it though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was very simple: I uninstalled the brew python and the pip-installed Cython and reinstalled both after which everything seem to work.

I think the problem was that I had installed python with brew having only Xcode installed. In the meantime - before I installed Cython - I installed Apple's Command Line Tools. So python and Cython was installed under different conditions which probably led to the error.

Comment: it worked, only thing that it installed quite lot newer version of python but yes it worked